# adding random shapes Rectangles, Ellipses and lines in JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, random, paint

Hey there i'm trying to design a GUI program ShapeFactory that has Buttons to produce :

a. Random Rectangles with random colors.

b. Random Ellipses with random colors.

c. Random Lines with random colors.

Whenever user clicks on a button, the corresponding shape will be added to the already drawn shapes in the JFrame.

and i'm stuck at trying to connect the ActionListener with the paint methode

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeFactory extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShapeFactory();
}

    JButton ranRects = new JButton("Random Rectangles");
    JButton ranElli = new JButton("Random Ellipses");
    JButton ranLines = new JButton("Random Lines");
    Graphics g;
    Color c;
    ArrayList shapeList = new ArrayList( );

public ShapeFactory(){
    super("Shape Factory");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(600,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(ranRects);
    add(ranElli);
    add(ranLines);

    JPanel nPanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout(1,3));
    nPanel.add(ranRects);
    nPanel.add(ranElli);
    nPanel.add(ranLines);

    add(nPanel);


    ranRects.addActionListener(this);

    ranElli.addActionListener(this);        

    ranLines.addActionListener(this);


    setVisible(true);
}

    public void paint (Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

    if (d == 1) {
        paintRect(g);
        shapeList.add(d);
        }

    else if (d == 2) {
        paintOval(g);
        shapeList.add(d);
        }

    else if (d == 3 ) {
        paintLine(g);
        shapeList.add(d);
        }
} 

    public void paintRect(Graphics g) {

        int rectX1 = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth() / 4.0);
        int rectY1 = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight()/ 4.0);
        int rectX2 = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth());
        int rectY2 = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight());
        c = new Color( (int) (Math.random() * 255) , (int) (Math.random() * 255) , (int) (Math.random() * 255));
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(rectX1,rectY2,rectX2,rectY2);
    }
    public void paintOval(Graphics g) {

        int ciX1 = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth() / 4.0);
        int ciY1 = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight()/ 4.0);
        int ciX2 = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth());
        int ciY2 = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight());
        c = new Color( (int) (Math.random() * 255) , (int) (Math.random() * 255) , (int) (Math.random() * 255));
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(ciX1,ciY1,ciX2,ciY2);
    }
    public void paintLine(Graphics g) {

        int lineX1 = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth() / 4.0);
        int lineY1 = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight()/ 4.0);
        int lineX2 = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth());
        int lineY2 = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight());
        c = new Color( (int) (Math.random() * 255) , (int) (Math.random() * 255) , (int) (Math.random() * 255));
        g.setColor(c);
        g.drawLine(lineX1,lineY1,lineX2,lineY2);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source == ranRects) { 
            d = 1;
        }
        else if (source == ranElli) {
            d = 2; 
        }
        else if (source == ranLines) {
            d = 3;

        }
        repaint();  

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there at any time only one of each shape that has to be drawn? Or should the button add a shape each time it's clicked?

Comment: it starts clear, when i click a button one of the shapes will appear then when i click on another button the next shape will be add to the current one and so on

Comment: i have changed some methods and i manged to link the ActionPerformed method to the Paint method.    how can i make them stay on the screen and not disappear ?

Comment: so you can click the rectangle button twice to have two rectangles appear?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: do i need to use a loop in the paint method?

Comment: You need to store all your shapes in a list. And than paint all of them in your `paintComponent` method (prefer to override the `paintComponent` method over `paint` method).

Comment: So if you want the position and color to stay the same each time the shape is drawn you'd need to save the shape and its properties somehow. Yes you may need to use a loop in the `paint` method if you want multiple shapes drawn at once

Comment: oh, so i don't need to use a loop!, i just need to save them in an Array List or Array to keep the shape that already been drawn ?

Comment: You'd still need the loop to iterate through the list or array to draw each shape. If I remember correctly every time `paint` is called the frame is cleared and everything needs to be redrawn

Comment: i actually got lost trying to store them ! any help please or modification on the code, im trying to use arraylist

Comment: *"im trying to use arraylist"* Show your attempt in a [mcve] as an [edit].

Comment: i made the edit on the code, i really don't know about arraylist because i haven' t used it before - i saw some explanation  about it online

Comment: why did you edited the question with this crap. make no sense !?!

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one solution would be to use 3 member variables to keep track of how many shapes of each type need to be drawn. Once a button is clicked you simply increment the corresponding variable and in the `paint` method you call the `paintOval` or whatever shape it is multiple times. In that case your `paint` method could look like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfRects; i++)
        paintRect(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfEllis; i++)
        paintOval(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfLines; i++)
        this.paintLine(g);
}
```

And the `actionPerformed` like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == ranRects) {
        this.numberOfRects++;
    } else if (source == ranElli) {
        this.numberOfEllis++;
    } else if (source == ranLines) {
        this.numberOfLines++;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

And you'd of course need to add the 3 member variables to the class.

---

If you want to store the shapes position and color I'd recommend to create a new class to store them in some sort of `List`. You could create a inner class `Shape` to store the shapes properties like position, size and color.

```
private class Shape{
    public int x1;
    public int y1;
    public int x2;
    public int y2;
    public Color color;
}
```

You could then add member variables for each type of shape:

```
private List<Shape> rectList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Shape> ovalList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Shape> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would recommend a method to add a shape like this:

```
public void addRect(){
    //Create new Shape
    Shape shape = new Shape();

    //Set shape's properties
    shape.x1 = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth() / 4.0);
    shape.x2 = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight() / 4.0);
    shape.y1 = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
    shape.y2 = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
    shape.color =  new Color((int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255));

    //Add the shape to the list
    this.rectList.add(shape);
}
```

and call the method in the actionListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == ranRects) {
        addRect();
    } else if (source == ranElli) {
        addOval();
    } else if (source == ranLines) {
        addLine();
    }
    repaint();
}
```

To draw them you'd simply iterate the list for each type of shape:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for (Shape s: rectList )
        paintRect(g, s);
    //...
    //Add loops for all shapes
}

public void paintRect(Graphics g, Shape shape) {
    g.setColor(shape.color);
    g.fillRect(shape.x1, shape.y1, shape.x2, shape.y2);
}
```

At the end you should have something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class ShapeFactory extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShapeFactory();
    }

    JButton ranRects = new JButton("Random Rectangles");
    JButton ranElli = new JButton("Random Ellipses");
    JButton ranLines = new JButton("Random Lines");
    private List<Shape> rectList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Shape> ovalList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Shape> lineList = new ArrayList<>();

    private class Shape{
        public int x1;
        public int y1;
        public int x2;
        public int y2;
        public Color color;
    }

    public ShapeFactory() {
        super("Shape Factory");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(ranRects);
        add(ranElli);
        add(ranLines);

        JPanel nPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        nPanel.add(ranRects);
        nPanel.add(ranElli);
        nPanel.add(ranLines);

        add(nPanel);


        ranRects.addActionListener(this);

        ranElli.addActionListener(this);

        ranLines.addActionListener(this);


        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (Shape s: rectList )
            paintRect(g, s);
        //...
        //Add loops for all shapes
    }

    public void paintRect(Graphics g, Shape shape) {
        g.setColor(shape.color);
        g.fillRect(shape.x1, shape.y1, shape.x2, shape.y2);
    }
    //...
    //Add paint methods for oval and lines

    public void addRect(){
        //Create new Shape
        Shape shape = new Shape();

        //Set shape's properties
        shape.x1 = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth() / 4.0);
        shape.x2 = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight() / 4.0);
        shape.y1 = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
        shape.y2 = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
        shape.color =  new Color((int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255));
        //Add the shape to the list

        this.rectList.add(shape);
    }
    //...
    //Add methods to add ovals and lines


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == ranRects) {
            addRect();
        } else if (source == ranElli) {
            //addOval();
        } else if (source == ranLines) {
            //addLine();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I've only implemented the `paint` and `add` methods for rectangles but it wouldn't be hard to add ovals and lines.
Hope this helped

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your work and time fixing this, i wish you the best :) !

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to hear that it helped you